# applet not working on browser

Tags: java, html, swing, packaging, japplet

I'm following some exercises on how to build applets; however, I'm not able to get it to show up in the browser. After trying for several times, and being sure that the applet was correct and so was the html page (both on same folder). I downloaded the same version of my applet from the author website (class + html) put them both in a folder and they worked. The strange thing is that both file are identical to mine, but mine aren't working... anyone could suggest what could be wrong? here are both of my files (very simple)

here the link to the applet on the web
http://www.cs.armstrong.edu/liang/intro8e/book/DisplayLabel.html

here are my files

html file

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Java Applet Demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <applet
      code = "DisplayLabel.class"
      width = 250
      height = 50>
    </applet>
  </body>
</html>
```

class file (java code)

```
package Chapter18Applets;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class DisplayLabel extends JApplet {

    public DisplayLabel() {
        add(new JLabel("This is an Applet!", 0));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package Chapter18Applets;
```

Remove that line. You are not using a package, so you don't need a `package` declaration.

Comment: Thanks.. that did it. but when I make changes to my applet, it is still showing the old applet in browser. I remove the class file, recreate it, and still shows the old applet. I refresh the browser and  still shows the old one. is only when I close the browser and reopened that show the updated one... has anyone experience that?

Comment: @miatech Try a force refresh (CTRL+F5) You might have to do it a couple times.

Answer (score 1):

Ok if you are going to use packages, you need to export your program as a .jar. If you are not going to use packages, do as the other person said and remove the line declaring the package statement.

Otherwise, once you do export and upload it as a .jar, you need to have the archive attribute which states that your program is in a .jar, and change your code attribute a bit to

```
<applet archive="name.jar" code="Character18Applets.DisplayLabel" width=x height=y>
```

Notice how your code attribute is packageName.ClassName. You DO NOT need the .class extension after it.

Hope this helps :)